# Discussing salary as a jr developer

Tags: salary, contractors, fulltime

I'm currently employed as a contractor as a jr php developer. I will be finding out within the next week if I will be hired as a full time employee.

This is my first 'real' job and make a nice amount of money hourly in it. I don't really know if I'm even going to be able or have the option to discuss my salary if hired but if I do, what should I ask for? This being my first time in this position I'm not sure if it's proper to try and get say $10 more an hour. I ask this because from my understanding, employers pay the people who contract me a LOT more than what they would pay if I wasn't a contractor.

Assume I'm making 28 an hour now. What should (or should I) try to get next?

and if it makes a difference I currently have no college degree (about 80 credits though) and do plan on getting my degree part-time (at night) so not interfering with work hours.

And what about benefits...I know they are offered (not sure what exactly though).

Comment: Assuming you are making 28 an hour now, no company is going to pay you 35% more to become full-time permanent. Usually they try to get you for less when going full-time because now they have to pay benefits. You can try asking for more but be more realistic in what you ask for.

Comment: If you are currently junior/contract, and they make you junior/permanent, that doesn't mean that you suddenly add tons more value to the company. It just means that they are confident enough in your work to change your payroll status. You are still junior level developer. Asking for a very substantial raise is probably out of place. Be satisfied with a small raise for now (or no raise), do your schooling, work for a few years, gain skills, become proficient, improve soft-skills, and then achieve mastery. As your skills grow and you being more value to the company, *then* ask for more money.

Comment: "I don't really know if I'm even going to be able or have the option to discuss my salary" - If they make an offer, you will always have the chance to accept it, reject it or try to negotiate. If you search for "negotiate salary" on here you will find plenty of related discussions.

Comment: A junior developer making 28? I've been doing this for years and I make 25. This is interesting to me. What area of the US do you live in?

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell you what to ask for. It depends on a staggering number of variables.

You should check sites such as Glass Door for what companies in that area are paying devs with your level of experience. There are many sources for this kind of information.

You should also consider your situation realistically. A lot of companies have different pay brackets based on education as well as experience. Here in Southern Ontario a college grad may make as much as 10K less than a university grad even though they're doing the same work (because a university education is seen as superior to college).

In any case, you should probably ask for at least the average salary that a junior dev in your area makes and go from there.

Also consider that the company might well be hiring you full time because they want to save some money compared to your hourly rates.

Comment: Agreed. They will likely give no raise or very little. Its possible they will want to negotiate for less money as they now have benefits and such to pay.